# Using assigned ID for domain object in Grails 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

We are using Grails with a legacy database and we need to control how ID's get assigned to domain objects.

We have tried:

```
id column: "sco_id", generator:'assigned'
```

but we get the exception:

> Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1

we have also tried to create a custom ID generator:

```
public class ScoIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) {

        /*Generate ID here*/

        return 8;
    }

}
```

But it seems like the generator is being ignored in this case so we get the error

```
DEFAULT keyword cannot be used as column has no DEFAULT
```

I am not sure if these issues are specific to Grails 2.

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here was that we were attempting to configure the id with the columns block

```
static mapping = {
    table "table_name"

    columns {
        id generator: 'assigned', column: "id_sco", sqlType: "int"
    }   
}
```

Instead we needed to configure the id directly inside the static mapping block

```
static mapping = {
    table "table_name"

    id generator: 'assigned', column: "id_sco", sqlType: "int"
    columns {
        ...
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a detailed answer. Someday it may help someone with the same problem as yours!